# How to fix IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0

Tags: python-3.x

here's my code. The program always gets error and outputting

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0
```

Its my first time learning how to code with python and I don't understand why the program got an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data= pd.read_csv('fifa20.csv') data.describe()

X = data.iloc[:, [2, 6]].values

m=X.shape[0] #number of training examples n=X.shape[1] #number of features.Here n=2 n_iter=100

K=4 # number of clusters

Centroid=np.array([]).reshape(n,0)

Output={}

EuclidianDistance=np.array([]).reshape(m,0) 
for k in range(K):
      tempDist=np.sum((X-Centroid[:,k])*2,axis=1)  #I got Index error in this line 
      EuclidianDistance=np.c_[EuclidianDistance,tempDist] 
C=np.argmin(EuclidianDistance,axis=1)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce your error by writing:

```
Centroid =  Centroid=np.array([]).reshape(n,0)
print(Centroid[:, 0])
```

You are indexing into an empty array, which will always lead to an index error.

To fix the issue, you should initialize Centroid to a non-empty array.